# Allow external provider to access Webfolder in CentOS. (Option SFTP)

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, sftp

Following Problem: We run a CentOS webserver and would like to grant access for an external contractor which only needs to access our webfolder ''/var/www' to Modify/Upload files.

What I tried was setting up SFTP jailing (according to the following documentation: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/), but I can't make it work because of the following reason: The whole webfolder has assigned the Apache User apache:apache as usual in CentOS. But SFTP needs to have root:root ownership otherwise following error appears:

fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/" [postauth]
So how can I setup SFTP or an other solution in order to keep the "www" folder apache:apache owned and allow an other user to access it?

Are there other options to solve this problem then SFTP or is SFTP the right thing to do?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you fully appreciate and understand Linux file permissions? Eg. https://codesport.io/security/the-ulitmate-guide-to-file-and-directory-permissions-on-ubuntu/

Comment: No, it is not. The condition is made for a reason (CVE-2009-2904). Some tools might allow you to do this, but they are making the whole thing less secure.

Comment: Found someone with the same problem and got it solved, thanks a lot! http://askubuntu.com/questions/196062/sftp-permission-denied-on-files-owned-by-www-data  it would be great if you could shortly check if my solution is still secure? (see answer below) thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used SFTP to solve the mentioned problem. The main issues where the file permissions. I did the following steps (running CentOS 7.2):

**Folder Permissions**
Following file permissions where set. Including the sticky bit (explained after the code).

```
sudo find /var/www/html/ -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;
sudo find /var/www/html/ -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \; # Set SGID in order to keep group for newly created files
sudo chown -R apache:webmasters /var/www/html/website/data/ # As data directory must be writable by apache
chown root:root /var/www/
```

**Create Group and Users**

Create user for external provider and set new password.

```
groupadd webmasters
useradd -g webmasters -d /var/www/ -s /sbin/nologin externalProvider
passwd externalProvider
```

**Setup sftp-server Subsystem in sshd_config**

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Outcomment existing Subsystem and and add:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

Add add the end of sshd_config

```
Match Group sftpusers
       Match Group webmasters
        ChrootDirectory /var/www/
        AllowTCPForwarding no
        X11Forwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Restart sshd service

```
systemctl restart sshd
```

**Login via SFTP to test the connection**

```
sftp externalProvider@hostname
```

**Security**

SELinux is enforcing and was never en issue concerning this SFTP setup.